# Get the Opposite of a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, yup

I want to validate a form field, by preventing the user from entering the domain name with www or http so I wrote a regular expression as follows.

```
/^(www|http)/
```

What I want is the opposite of the written regular expression. So that I can have the expected result.

Expected result:

- www.google.com  - invalid
- http://apple.co.uk - invalid
- http://www.water.com -invalid
- google.com - should be valid
- apple.co.uk - should be valid

How to get the opposite of the regular expression

Comment: You need to use negative lookahead like this `/^(?!www|http).*/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kqeic3/1)

Comment: you could write a regex that matches what you want then negate it in javascript `!regex.test(url)`

Comment: Thank you @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You saved my day.